# Validar assinatura digital com PHP gerado por TCPDF

Tags: php, certificado-digital, assinatura-digital, tcpdf

Olá, estou desenvolvendo uma aplicação em `PHP` que teria a feature de assinar documentos digitalmente com o A1, sei que no âmbito `desktop` isso é muito mais fácil, mas quero fazer em `PHP`.
Já assinei com o [TCPDF exemplo 52](https://tcpdf.org/examples/example_052/), e gostaria de saber com base na assinatura feita pelo [TCPDF](https://tcpdf.org), como que eu posso validar ela e pegar os dados da assinatura digital.
O código que usei é o mesmo do exemplo acima(TCPDF).

Comment: Você quer, com PHP, pegar a assinatura digital gerada pelo TCPDF, isso?

Comment: isso mesmo ! não sei se é possível, e se for, como posso fazer ?

Comment: Eu entendo muito pouco de PDF assinado digitalmente, entretanto, valide se essa resposta não lhe ajuda: https://stackoverflow.com/a/38059720/1628790

Comment: ok, vou dar uma olhada nesse link, muito obrigado.